# Change the values of a variable (emotion, 0-5 scale to 5-0 scale)

Tags: r

I want to measure the emotion transition of people based on their answer to a survey which asked questions like 'on a scale 0-5, how cheerful do you feel: 0 not at all cheerful, 5 very cheerful" or 'on a scale 0-5, how stressed do you feel: 0 not at all stressed, 5 very stressed'. Data look like this:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq2mE.jpg)

I need to rescale the level for all positive emotion questions, so:5 to 0, 4 to 1, 3 to 2, 2 to 3, 1 to 4, 0 to 5.

I tried to write some code but I don't think it is correct since by the end of the code every 0 will be changed from 5 to 0 again:

```
mood_cleaned$cheerful[mood_cleaned$cheerful==0] <- 5
mood_cleaned$cheerful[mood_cleaned$cheerful==1] <- 4
mood_cleaned$cheerful[mood_cleaned$cheerful==2] <- 3
mood_cleaned$cheerful[mood_cleaned$cheerful==3] <- 2
mood_cleaned$cheerful[mood_cleaned$cheerful==4] <- 1
mood_cleaned$cheerful[mood_cleaned$cheerful==5] <- 0
```

The code is also too long, I have 13 variables to be changed so there's got to be an easier way? Thank you!

Comment: I've answered this [a minute before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998554/6574038) in another question ;)

Comment: @jay.sf thank you very much, it works! though it will convert the data to a list and my intention is to keep it still as numerics, it is interesting to see that there are so many ways to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through data frame and changing values on condition \[R\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997790/iterating-through-data-frame-and-changing-values-on-condition-r)

Comment: @Siyou I thought you would already understand the concept. See my answer below which is actually the essence of my other answer.

Comment: This feels like a school exercise. Too basic. Code to doing this shouldn't be 'too long'. Basically you should return the result of 5 minus the value set in the mood by the user. So if the user chose 0, then 5 minus 0 = 5. If the user chose 3, then 5 minus 3 = 2.
You don't mention what language are you using, nor your code. You should add that info and you should also check the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you do it sequentially not at the same time. You have several options, including `recode()`, `case_when`,etc. but in your case the simplest operation would be the same for all columns:

`mood_cleaned$cheerful <- (mood_cleaned$cheerful-5)*-1`

This should do what you want, e.g. (5-5)*-1=0, (4-5)*-1=1 and so on.

Alternatively by the way:

```r
library(dplyr)

mood_cleaned %>%
mutate(cheerful = (cheerful-5)*-1)

# or this way

mood_cleaned %>%
mutate(cheerful = case_when( cheerful == 5 ~ 0,
                             cheerful == 4 ~ 1,
                             ...)

# or with a fancy self-defined function

reverse_scale <- function(column){
new_value = (column-max(column))*-1
}

mood_cleaned$cheerful <- reverse_scale(mood_cleaned$cheerful)
```

Edit:

I also saw you need to do 13 variables at once so this solution should be best:

```r
library(dplyr)

# define universal function to reverse scaleS
reverse_scale <- function(column){
new_value = (column-max(column))*-1
}

# apply in dplyr logic to all columns
mood_cleaned %>%
 mutate_at(.vars = 2:15, .funs = reverse_scale) # this works for columns 2 to 15, change numbers as needed

# or 

mood_cleaned %>%
 mutate_at(.vars = -1, .funs = reverse_scale) # this works for all columns except the first one
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an assignment matrix as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998554/6574038). You don't need the `lapply` here since you only want to manipulate a single column.

```
df1$cheerful <- c(4, 1, 5, 2, 0, 3)
df1
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 cheerful
# 1  X  X  X  X        4
# 2  X  X  X  X        1
# 3  X  X  X  X        5
# 4  X  X  X  X        2
# 5  X  X  X  X        0
# 6  X  X  X  X        3

am <- matrix(c(0:5, 5:0),,2)
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    5
# [2,]    1    4
# [3,]    2    3
# [4,]    3    2
# [5,]    4    1
# [6,]    5    0

df1$cheerful <- am[match(df1$cheerful, am[, 1]), 2]
df1  
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 cheerful
# 1  X  X  X  X        1
# 2  X  X  X  X        4
# 3  X  X  X  X        0
# 4  X  X  X  X        3
# 5  X  X  X  X        5
# 6  X  X  X  X        2
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), X2 = c("X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), X3 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"
), X4 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler

```
mood_cleaned$cheerful <- 5 - mood_cleaned$cheerful
```

or for a list of variables

```
for(this_mood in c("cheerful", "ecstatic")){
  mood_cleaned[this_mood] = 5 - mood_cleaned[this_mood] 
}
```